# Can I use diluted essential oils to clean my house without causing harm to my cat?

Tags: cats, safety, cleaning

I would like to add a few drops to the water I use to mop my floors but I'm not sure if it would be harmful to my cats.

I don't plan on using it on their toys, just on the floors (they do lay on the floor though).

I know that using essential oils directly to the cat is harmful, but this is not at all my intention.

I plan on using around 5 drops to about 5 liters of water. It could be tea tree, eucalyptus, lavender or lemon. They are organic, if it is important (and no mlm!).

Is it safe or is it better to avoid essential oils completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](https://www.thesprucepets.com/dangers-of-essential-oils-555089) indicates that lavender oil is the only oil of your list not toxic for cats.

[The Pet Poison Helpline](https://www.petpoisonhelpline.com/blog/essential-oils-cats/) is of particular intetest because it lists the different ways cats might come in contact with essential oils (touching, ingesting, breathing in) and how it affects the cat. They also have a list of symptoms to watch out for.

Please keep in mind that cats absorb toxins over the soles of their feet and lack a certain enzyme to break down those toxins, causing them to accumulate ovrr time. So you don't want to use any toxic oils in mopping, even in small quantities.

If the reason for adding essential oils to the mopping water is to have your rooms smell pleasant to you, I suggest using a [passive oil diffuser](https://www.diffuseressentials.com/passive-diffusers/) instead. Don't place it too close to your cats favorite spot or cat tree. If you block direct access to the dispenser, you could even try using oils toxic to cats *in small quantities*. If the cat shows any negative symptoms like coughing or heavy breathing, remove the oil immediately and air the room.

Please keep in mind that a cats sense of smell is much better than that of a human. Fragranting the air too much might cause your cat discomfort, no matter if the oil is toxic or not.

Comment: thank you so much! all the input you provided is very valuable! I think I will avoid the oils altogether.