# Bitter Spray so that cat stops licking himself?

Tags: cats, health

One of my cats has a small scrape in one of his paws. He continues licking it and it never heals.

What spray can I use so that he stops licking his paw?

I tried one of the DIY remedies on the web. My cat laughed at me and then started licking. In other words, it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Please in any case you read to use citrus oils or similar: cats can get ill from simple walking over surfaces cleaned with citrus oil. So do not use it at the paw. Have alook into the following pets.SE Question, to read about essential oils and the risk for cats: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21166/can-i-use-diluted-essential-oils-to-clean-my-house-without-causing-harm-to-my-ca/21188#21188

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a cone is the solution? Either a standard cone, which would prevent the cat to lick any part of their body, or a small cone (if it exists) just for the paw.

Or maybe consult a veterinarian about a solution, they should have more professional experience and solutions.